# Testing a mocked Observable converted to a promise in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a Angular service I want to test, one get function returns transformed data:

```
getSomeThings(pageSize) {
    return this.http
        .get(`../assets/things.json`)
        .map((response) => response.json())
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            return response.map((thing) => {
                return new Thing(thing);
            });
        }).then(response => {
            response.slice(0, pageSize)
        });
    }
}
```

I'm testing this as below:

```
describe('ThingsService', () => {
    let service: ThingsService;
    let mockHttp;
    const things = [{ id: 1, title: 'hello' }, { id: 2, title: 'hello' }, { id: 3, title: 'hello' }, { id: 4, title: 'hello' },
    { id: 5, title: 'hello' }, { id: 6, title: 'hello' }, { id: 7, title: 'hello' }, { id: 8, title: 'hello' }, { id: 9, title: 'hello' },
    { id: 10, title: 'hello' }, { id: 11, title: 'hello' }, { id: 12, title: 'hello' }];

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockHttp = new Http(undefined, undefined)
        service = new ThingsService(mockHttp);

        spyOn(mockHttp, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of(things)).and.callThrough();
    });

    it('should have a length of 10', async(() => {

        mockHttp.get.and.returnValue(Observable.of(things));
        return service.getThings(10)
            .then((returnedThings: any[]) => {
                expect(returnedThings.length).toBe(10)
            });
    }));
});
```

This returns an error:

```
response.json is not a function
```

things[] has a length of 12, but there's a slice in the final then() which should only return 10.
I'm quite new to Jasmine so could've easily missed some fundamentals here. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is `response` undefined at all?

Comment: actually response is a json array, which may be the issue, ill convert it to a string and test

Comment: Hmm, if it's already JSON then will you need to call `.json()` on it?

Comment: In production yes, as the call actually returns a response, which has the .json() method on it. a standard array does not, can i tell jasmine to ignore this call? or get the data in a format which will work with .json()?

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean now. I think Milad's answer should work and will provide a decent enough mock response for your test to pass. Suppressing the error isn't advisable as it could allow a bug to slip through in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const things = {
       json:function(){
          return [{ id: 1, title: 'hello' }, { id: 2, title: 'hello' }, { id: 3, title: 'hello' }, { id: 4, title: 'hello' },
    { id: 5, title: 'hello' }, { id: 6, title: 'hello' }, { id: 7, title: 'hello' }, { id: 8, title: 'hello' }, { id: 9, title: 'hello' },
    { id: 10, title: 'hello' }, { id: 11, title: 'hello' }, { id: 12, title: 'hello' }];
       }

  }
```

Comment: This does work, but is it the 'correct' way to test a service? I suppose the .json() method doesn't belong to the subject of the test, in this case my service, I'm still trying to work out what's considered dirty in this world

Comment: yep , this is actually the correct way, you're mocking the response. There are better ways, but they all fall into this way

Comment: And don't worry too much about dirtiness, it's always dirty at the end